# Function calculation date (Except Sunday day, july and August month)

Tags: php

Hello I am looking to do a date calculation function. I have a first date for example 2018-06-29 and I would like to add 30 days to this date, if by adding 30 days I fall on a Sunday I would like to withdraw -1 day so fall on a Saturday, the date recover from the calculation will be 2018-07-28 and so on ....

If the date falls in the month of July, we will postpone for the month of June, and if we fall in August, we will postpone the month of September.

Currently I get the first date like this

```
Array
(
    [date_delivery] => 2018-06-27
)
```

And I prepare the calculation function

```
public function calculDate($dateDelivery)
{
    ddd($dateDelivery);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what have you tried? Adding a date interval to a date is well documented, checking for the date conditions is not difficult either

Comment: It's bad practice to want us to code that for you. Read the docs and try things out.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcDate($date) {
    $newDate = strtotime('+1 month',$date);
    $day = day('D',$newDate);
    if ($day == 'Sun') $newDate = strtotime('-1 day', $newDate);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help #QuodNephilim I will test your function.